# OnErrorThrowable not found in rxjava 2

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I am upgrading rxjava 1 to rxjava 2. There is OnErrorThrowable in rxjava 1 but not found in rxjava 2. What can I do in the following code to replace the OnErrorThrowable?

```
static Observable<String> sampleObservable() {
    return Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<String> call() throws Exception {
            try {
                // Do some long running operation
                Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw OnErrorThrowable.from(e);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "The sleep is over, now produce something");
            return Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2.x, you don't have to wrap exceptions as all functional types declare `throws Exception`:

```
static Observable<String> sampleObservable() {
return Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableSource<String> call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
        Log.d(TAG, "The sleep is over, now produce something");
        return Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Hey David, what about cases like `onErrorReturn()`, where we used to previously re-throw the error using `OnErrorThrowable.from()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can return `Observable.error(e);` instead of throwing in your catch block.